# NodeJS: How to synchronously exewcute shell command and detects errors

Tags: node.js, shell

I want to synchronously execute a shell command and check the result of shell command if there was any errors.

Therefor I use [shellJS](https://github.com/shelljs/shelljs) and its exec-method.

Unfortunately the success-handlers will never reached. Any statement after my shell.exec-statement gets executed immediately.

This is my code:

```
function * exec(cmd, verbose) {
    if(verbose) console.log("\nCMD " + cmd);

    var ret = 0;

    shell.exec(cmd, function(code, stdout, stderr) {
        console.log("AAAAA")
        ret = code;
        if(code !== 0) console.log(stderr)
    });

    console.log("BBBBB")

    if(ret !== 0 && ret !== undefined) {
        console.log("ERROR: there is an error occured: ", ret);
        process.exit();
    }
    return ret;
}
```

I call this method with:

```
yield exec('ls -l', true);
yield exec('ls -l ..', true);
```

The console.log("AAA") appear at the end of the app after all other console.logs....
The console.log("BBB") appears immediately before any output was triggered by the shell.exec-command.

The README of shell.js explains:

> Executes the given command synchronously, unless otherwise specified.
>   When in synchronous mode, this returns a ShellString (compatible with
>   ShellJS v0.6.x, which returns an object of the form { code:...,
>   stdout:... , stderr:... }). Otherwise, this returns the child process
>   object, and the callback gets the arguments (code, stdout, stderr).

Any ideas? What do i wrong.,

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:
https://github.com/shelljs/shelljs
[image]

"If a callback is provided, it [async] will be set to true".

Don't pass a callback. Call it like:

```
var child = shell.exec(command);
child.stdout.on('data', data => {
  /* ... do something with data ... */
});
```